# Android signalr network change timeout

Tags: android, signalr, samsung-mobile, xamarin.forms, samsung-galaxy

Hi everyone I have a question for you. I have a project that is using xamarin forms and in this project we are using the signalr client. Whenever I switch from Wi-Fi to cellular data my signal are times out. However the weird thing is that no statechanged events ever fire on a client side not even the disconnect, and I can still send messages with the proxy to other clients but it doesn't receive messages from the other clients. I had a question last week where servicestack was timing out when I switched from Wi-Fi to mobile and the solution was to put a connection header in the request that was set to close. I tried that with the signalr connection but it doesn't work. I've also tried to use the project modernhttpclient and that doesn't work either. On the server side I've even tried saying the keepalive to know so that way it only uses the connection timeout and the disconnect timeout.

Some other weird information about this problem is that it doesn't happen on all Android devices. It seems to work on the Samsung  and a different Android device possibly a Nexus device. The reason I know this is that my coworkers have these phones and it works perfectly fine for them. However my device, which is a samsung galaxy s6 edge comma does not work with the code that was implemented for reconnecting when did not work changes

Comment: I don't know about the Xamarin client, but I know that the java client for Android is fragile at best. It would attempt to reconnect and immediately give up. I had to tie it in with our connectivity service to reconnect on demand.

Comment: @323go I assume you wrote your SignalR client in native java then?

Comment: We used [this one](https://github.com/SignalR/java-client).